# Error: Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

import { ICustomRoute } from "../types";
import Loader from '../loader'

const LoginPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/login"));
const LoginSuccessPage = lazy(() => import("../pages/auth/login/success"));

export const authRoutes: ICustomRoute[] = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <LoginPage />
      </Suspense>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "welcome",
        element: (
          <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
            <LoginSuccessPage />
          </Suspense>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm only export one thing (authRoutes) from this file, but I get this error in my Vite app

```
Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components. Move your component(s) to a separate file.eslint(react-refresh/only-export-components)
```

I moved the lazy imports into an 'imports.ts' file and exported from there, then imported them into the routes file and everything works fine. I feel like this is a bit convoluted. Is there a better way to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error, a bit different use, but I also had a Utilities.tsx file where I abstracted away functions, error happened when I tried to have both function exports and component exports at the same time.

```
export const sum = (a,b) => {
return a + b
}
export const Component = () => {
return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

This would cause an error since it has both functions and components being exported.  You must have a separate file that exports your reusable or abstracted components in order for Fast Refresh to work.

Answer (score 0):

restart the localhost , at the develop time i stop the local server and start again its work for stop 'ctrl +c' and start 'npm run dev'

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error, the way i could fix it was that i changed my file extension from .tsx to .ts and added .ts to to filename when importing it